# A general question about constructing subsequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I am currently covering sequences and the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).  My question is regarding construction of subsequences. This material is still new to me and I am in a class that is designed for people heading into Real Analysis.

An example:

"A sequence that does not contain 0 or 1 as a term but contains subsequences converging to each of these values."

It took me a while but I was able to construct a sequence using a piece-wise argument.

$$
x_n=\begin{cases}
  1+\dfrac1n,&\text{n is odd}\\
  \dfrac1n,&\text{n is even}
\end{cases}
$$

Since $\left\{1+\dfrac1n\right\}\rightarrow 1$ and $\left\{\dfrac1n\right\}\rightarrow 0$.

But even this feels rather cheap because I have no way of expressing it as a single subsequence say $(x_{n_k})\color{red}{\text{ (correct me if I am wrong!)}}$. As in, I cannot manipulate the subscript to give me the desired equation. This worries me because I do not have a closed form of a subsequence $-$ as example, if then I am asked to show said subsequences converge, I would not know what to do.

For example we know $(x_n)\rightarrow 0$ where $x_n=\dfrac1n$

then we can show the subsequence $(x_{2n})\rightarrow 0$ where $x_{2n}=\dfrac1{2n}$

and the same follows with $(x_{2n+1})$, etc.

which is fairly easy to show using theorems of convergence, but these do not have the restrictions as the example.

I am wondering if there is an easier method or an approach to finding such subsequences rather than trial and error? I suppose this one was easy as I was able to think of plenty of sequences that converge to these values, yet I still feel as if it is incorrect with how it was constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the sequence that you constructed; it is one of the simplest that will do what you want.

You do have a closed form for the terms of the sequence: you’ve described $x_n$ directly in terms of $n$. Yes, it’s a multipart definition, but there’s nothing wrong with that. As it happens, it *could* be rewritten with a single formula, but the result would be less easily understood:

$$x_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n}2+\frac1n\,.\tag{1}$$

Sometimes, however, there is no nice formula that covers all indices; it really doesn’t matter as long as the terms of the sequence can be defined somehow.

And it appears to me that you’ve already seen that the relevant subsequences are easily described: one is

$$\langle x_{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\left\langle\frac1{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle\,,$$

and the other is

$$\langle x_{2n+1}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle=\left\langle\frac1{2n+1}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle\,.$$

I don’t know what you mean by ‘these do not have the restrictions as the example’: they are very straightforwardly subsequences of the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ defined by your two-part definition or, equivalently, by the more opaque $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thoughtful response, as a student I really appreciate it! Sorry what I meant by restrictions was the values we want excluded but still converge to. For example, a sequence that does not contain $x$ or $y$ as a term where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily $0$ or $1$), but contains subsequences converging to each of these values. Is there a closed form in general for these type of problems? Or is that usually uncommon?

Comment: @Trap.Lord: You’re very welcome. For this specific type of problem I would do something along the lines of what you did here: if $x<y$, for instance, I might alternate terms from the sequences $x-\frac1n$ and $y+\frac1n$, the signs ensuring that no term in the first sequence is $y$, and no term in the second sequence is $x$. That could be viewed as a pretty concrete recipe, and it can easily be generalized to any finite number of subsequences with distinct limits. More generally, though, it tends to be a matter of thinking about what has to happen to get a desired result and then trying ...

Comment: ... to make that happen. If you do enough such problems, you’ll probably find yourself starting to notice patterns, ideas that you use repeatedly, but my experience is that in general each problem has to be considered on its own merits.